# Why did Scala SIP-21 authors choose the name Spores?

Tags: scala

After reading through Scala [SIP-21](http://docs.scala-lang.org/sips/pending/spores.html), a proposal to add a new construct to increase the safety of closures in concurrent and distributed environments, I am curious as to why the authors chose the name *Spores* in particular for this concept. I haven't found any other references to this name in other Computer Science literature, so it appears novel to this SIP.

I can loosely see the how the dispersal of many small, simple structures and perhaps the capability for dormancy could be evocative of distributed closures. But is there some stronger connection here, a more involved metaphor?